# How to send multiple files with a read stream in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

If I have a directory with two files and I want to send send both of them.  Hypothetically and index.html and style.css.

```
Router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var indexStream = fs.createWriteStream('path to index')
  var cssStream = fs.createWriteStream('path to style')

  indexStream.pipe(res)
  styleStream.pipe(res)

})
```

As I understand `.pipe(res)` implicitly calls res.end() so I can send to separate read streams.  Thanks for any help~

Comment: What you're suggesting would effectively be concatenating two files together, is that really what you want to serve to the client? Typically a css file would be served separately by a static middleware instead.

Comment: So I the index.html page has a script tag for the styles.css in the same directory.  I noticed when I made a GET to `'/'`, it would make another GET to `'/styles.css'`.  I was wondering what the best way to serve both of these two static assets using streams would be?  This is more an exercise in plain node as I feel like I've glossed over a lot just using express for a long time.

Comment: @jhernandez: HTTP doesn't work that way. HTTP1.1 (the current standard) does have a feature to do it called pipelining. But it requires that the browser make the request using the same socket. If you send multiple responses to the browser for a single request the browser would not know what to do. All modern web browsers have disabled pipelining (you can't even turn it on in Chrome) due to buggy implementations on web servers. So this will only benefit Firefox users who are savvy enough to turn on pipelining (but not the way you're doing it).

Comment: @jhernandez: Sorry, there is a way to do this in a slightly different way. It's the keep-alive header: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection. But not the way you're doing it.

Comment: @jhernandez: Looks like node http.Server already supports `keep-alive`. See the docs: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request. The way it works is that you don't modify the code at all. Because http.Server will create a new `req` and `res` object for each request (not connection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't do this.

It's not a limitation of Node.js. It's a limitation of your web browser (or rather, a limitation of HTTP). What you do instead is send each file separately:

```
Router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('path to index')
})
Router.get('/style.css', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('path to style')
})
```

Alternatively if your router supports it you can use a static middleware to serve your css files.

---

#### Doesn't this create lots of connections?

Yes, and no.

If your browser supports it, node http.Server supports `keep-alive`. That means it will re-use an already opened connection if possible. So if you're worried about latency and want to implement persistent connections then it's already taken cared of for you.

If you want, you can change the `keep-alive` timeout by setting `server.timeout` but I think the default value of 2 minutes is more than enough for most web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd serve your html from a route handler and have all static assets automatically handled by the [`express.static()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#express.static) middleware.

You can also use [`res.sendFile()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.sendFile) to simplify things even further.

So you could have something like:

```
// Use whatever the correct path is that should be the root directory
// for serving your js, css, and other static assets.
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// ...

Router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('path to index');
});
```